# How to setup zend framework website without .htaccess

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

The setup of my .htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Guys i need your expertise on this one. Advice or idea would be great.
What i want to happen is that, i'll remove my .htaccess file and create a index.php to configure everything... Is it possible?

Can you please give some examples. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if i understand the question then no. well you can use httpd.conf, but i don't think that's much help in this case. I cant imagine what you have against .htaccess

Comment: +Dagon Just a guess but my bet is on a cheap webhosting service :-)

Comment: then easy solution, get a real host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

REFERENCE BY : http://www.armando.ws/2009/03/how-to-run-zend-framework-with-no-htaccess-file/

## Application Specific Include file

Include conf/extra/httpd-zf.conf

This will allow Apache to add addition configuration settings once Apache is restarted and its a great place to isolate application specific Apache settings.

Now, go ahead an create the include file, “httpd-zf.conf” inside the APACHE_HOME/conf/extra/ directory and place the ReWrite rules which were originally in your .htaccess file into
it.  Hit save, remove the .htaccess file, and restart Apache.  You should see your Zend Framework application running.

Why do this?
Speed. Your application must always read the .htaccess file when someone visits the site. Removing this extra layer and placing it into the Web Server itself will reduce the amount of time a page loads.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this solution, seems quite perfect, however I'm having trouble at the code inside `httpd-zf.conf` I just can't get Apache to start or, if it starts, I just can't get into my `public` folder Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

the rewrite part is part of apache, and as such can only be configured in a way apache understands, so you can use .htaccess or the vhost config file directly. no other way.

the APPLICATION_ENV you could set in your index.php, but its there for a reason. so you dont have to change your code in different stagings/installation of your app.